# Firefox addon-sdk: Removing bookmarks on uninstall

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to remove some bookmarks when uninstalling my addon. I've tried using onUnload, but it doesn't work. I think it's asynchronous save() function fault. Any ideas?

```
exports.onUnload = function (reason) {
  if (reason == "disable") {
    save(remove(bookmarks[id]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `save(bookmarks[id])` and then `remove(bookmarks[id])`?

Comment: You mean first remove then save, yes?
`remove(bookmarks[id]);
save(bookmarks[id]);`
remove() only sets "remove=true" in bookmark object. You have to save() it later. I've tried anyway, doesn't work.